# react-hook-form: setValue is clearing unregistered nested values

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form v7.5.0.

I have created a very simplified demo below, and on code sandbox. Nested unregistered fields in default values are cleared when `setValues` is done. Is there a way to retain nested unregistered values?

#### Explanation with reproduction

I have a related demo pasted below and in codesandbox.

We see `nested.firstName` and `nested.enabled` are "registered" due to `watch("nested.enabled")` and `<input type="text" {...form.register("nested.firstName")} />`. We see `nested.lastName` is NOT registered. The demo will show this value vanish.

1. Load that snippet, and on first render you see `form.getValues()` gets logged which outputs:

```
  {
    "msg": "render values",
    "values": {
      "nested": {
        "firstName": "foo",
        "lastName": "bar",
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
```

2. Tap the "toggle"
3. We see on next render the log output now shows:

```
  {
    "msg": "render values",
    "values": {
      "nested": {
        "firstName": "foo",
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
```

We see that `nested.lastName` has vanished!

#### Question

Does anyone know why this is? And how to make it stay?

#### Demo and code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-setvalues-clears-unregistred-default-values-livx0

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const form = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    form.reset({
      nested: {
        firstName: "foo",
        lastName: "bar",
        enabled: false
      }
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(
    JSON.stringify({ msg: "render values", values: form.getValues() }, null, 2)
  );

  const enabled = form.watch("nested.enabled");

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" {...form.register("nested.firstName")} />

      <button onClick={() => form.setValue("nested.enabled", !enabled)}>
        Set "enabled" to {String(!enabled)}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v7 this is intended behaviour, so that only the registered inputs, which will get rendered by your component are in the form state. As you don’t register “lastName”, it won’t be available in your form state.

I had a similar problem some time ago and asked for help on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/4565#discussioncomment-564533) is a bit of an explanation, why this is happening since v7:

> - first render watch will return defaultValues or defaultValue from    useWatch/watch
> - then your component is getting to the render phase
> - here we will need to register to invoked and getting all the inputs    during the render
> - once it's render is ended all inputs reference are    inside hook form (This is the step missing)
> - watch will return what's    in the view (which registered)

In this [comment](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/4565#discussioncomment-562182) from the discussion you can also find both CodeSandbox comparing this mounting behaviour for v6 and v7.

As my app used v6 i stayed with that version and didn't update to v7 as an update would have meant a lot of refactoring. I guess for v7 you would need to use another state utility like `useState` and merge it with your current form data.

Comment: Aw dang, thanks so much for sharing this. It was driving me crazy. I hope they bring a solution to this problem. I will store state separately for now. Thank you!

Comment: That's great. Glad I could help!

Comment: He landed a fix for our issue here! It's v7.6.0 - https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/pull/5069

Comment: Super cool! Thanks a lot for letting me know!!

Comment: @knoefel can you look at my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757532/react-hook-form-method-setvalue-doesnt-work