# React hook form method - setValue - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-hook-form

I have some clearable select, and I want to reset the `applets` field in state to an empty array.

```
const defaultFormValues = { device: { ...initialDevice }, applets: [] };
  const { control, getValues, setValue, reset, handleSubmit } = useForm<CreateDeviceFormData>({
    mode: "all",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: defaultFormValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onChangeHandler = React.useCallback(
    (value: Experience | null) => {
      if (value) {
        setValue("applets", getApplets(value));
      } else {
        setValue("applets", []);
        // reset(defaultFormValues);
      }

      setValue("device.experience_id", value ? value.id : undefined);
    },
    [templateSelector, setValue],
  );

  console.log("current data", getValues(), control);
  return (
    <>
      <SomeAutocompleteComponent control={control} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
      <SelectAppletsComponent control={control} />
    </>
  );


export const SelectAppletsComponent = ({ control, onChange }) => {
  const applets = useWatch({ control, name: "applets" }) as Applet[];
  const device = useWatch({ control, name: "device" }) as Device;

  if (!applets.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <SpanWrapper className="p-col-8">
      {applets.map((applet) => (
        <LabelRadio
          key={applet.id}
          inputId={applet.applet_type}
          value={applet.applet_type}
          label={applet.name}
          checked={device.applet_type === applet.applet_type}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
    </SpanWrapper>
  );
};
```

the problem is that clearing the selection on UI with `setValue("applets", []);` not working for some reason, and I don't understand why, and how to do it without `reset` method, which resets the whole state, not just single property as I understand

Comment: What does your SomeSelectComponent onChange look like?

Comment: here `onChangeHandler`, it's called with null or value - it's all that you need to know ) The problem with `setValue` method.

Comment: And is `device.experience_id` a form field or do you just use RHF's form state to update and save the value?

Comment: @knoefel device.experience_id is used as a select selected value, but I use `applets` just as RHF state, without registering, i guess some problems with this. Yes select component is some registered external component (via Controller) and I have no issue with it. `applets` is not bound to select, it used to render some things below select, I will modify source a little so it wouldbe easy to understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always register fields if you want to use them as RHF's form state.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    register("applets");
  }, [register]);
```

This fixes an issue.

**Update:**
Also a new method `resetField` is available

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up on this, it is indeed the right solution provided by AuthorProxy.

Using defaultValues doesn't register the fields (it seems that they are still added to the formData on submit, but since they are not registered, any user triggered changes to these fields won't reflect on the formData).

You have to register every field you want the user to be able to interact with.
We usually register fields via inputs in the JSX, but we also need to register the array since there is no input for it in the JSX.

As per shown by the author of the react hook form library.

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3160

And sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wood-4z0n0?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I ended up with using Controller in each component per file, it registers it automatically